# How to produce a simple ZTV/ZVI in openWind?

Tags: analysis

I'm struggling to get to grips with openWind. I need to produce a ZTV showing a 5km radius around the chimney of a proposed industrial development. I'm not sure of the height of the stack yet but for argument's sake let's say it's 60m. I heard that I could pretend that this is a turbine by creating a new turbine type. I set the hub at 60m but it asks for the rotor diameter so not sure what to do there.

I'm using Ordnance Survey (UK) open data - have downloaded the raster and DTM for the area I need and added them as new layers in openWind.

Here's where I'm starting to get confused and just want to make sure I'm on the right track. I've taken the DTM and set it to terrain elevation. Then created a raster based on this which looks right to me. I've set my custom turbine position and now set a ZVI going. It's taking a very long time so I'll have to wait and see if it's right. Is there a way to set just the 5km radius though for the ZVI?

Any help greatly received.